Is there a way to control presets in Dante Controller using Raspberry Pi?
I'm looking to design a rail in my audio booth for my operators to hit for different presets in Dante Controller without actually having to open up the program to change settings. I am new with Raspberry Pi configuring so any help would be appreciated!
